# Mongoose Error: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using MongoAtlas to connect my db. I've read on some post that the error might be my connection, but it's correct, if I write a wrong user or password it gives me auth error. Another response was to delete all .json files and node-modules, nothing. Last thing I tried was change the mongoAtlas network options to accept diffent IPs and creating a new cluster. I don't know what to try. Here's my code:

**auth.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../common/models/User');

require('dotenv').config()

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

// Conexión a Base de datos
const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri,
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}
)
.then(() => {
    console.log('Base de datos conectada');
})
.catch(e => console.log('error db:', e))




//registers a new user
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const user = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    try {
        const savedUser = await user.save((err, saved) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              } 
              else {  
                 console.log(saved); 
                 res.json({ mensaje : 'El cliente se agregó correctamente'}); 
              }
        });
        res.json({
            errores: null,
            data: savedUser
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({error: "aaaa"})
    }
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log('Authentication service started on port 5000');
});
```

It throws the error on post trying to save a new user.
Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

**User.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 255,
        index: { unique: true }
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 1024,
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at' }, collection: 'users' });


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: What do you want actually?

Comment: Apart from the timeout error, there are errors in your code as well. You cannot send res.json() in consecutive lines. You have to remove either of these two - `res.json({ mensaje : 'El cliente se agregó correctamente'})` or `res.json({ errores: null, data: savedUser})`.

Comment: Yep, that's solved but still getting timeout error. I just want to save this model to my mongoatlas, but keep geting timeout error